# git merge from branch didn't work, git merge using commit did, what happened?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-flow

I was trying to follow the gitflow, so I created a branch named develop, then a branch named with my feature ticket, did some changes and commited them.

Now, after a checkout I perform

```
$ git merge #611
```

And I get

> ```
> Already up to date.
> ```

However they were different:

```
$ git branch -vv
  #611               ca944c8 refs #611 clean repo and create new user settings
* develop            ac605bd [origin/develop] Apk after sprint of November
```

I took note of the commit number and performed

```
$ git merge ca944c8
```

And everything worked as I was expecting.

What am I doing wrong? If I do several commits on a row, Shall I merge every individual commit?

Comment: Try `git show #611`, ensure it shows the right thing, the hash at the start might trip up git and specify something other than what you think it does.

Comment: What does `git merge-base #611 develop` return? If it's `ca944c8`, then `develop` is ahead of `#611`.

Comment: @ElpieKay - Since malarres was able to get the merge to happen by using the commit ID, we can assume that at the time the merge was attempted `develop` was not ahead of `#611`.  If this test were attempted now that the merge has been completed, of course, it would show a false positive.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger You are right. I just missed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely your command shell interpreted the `#` at the beginning of your branch name as the beginning of a comment, so it executed

```
git merge
```

By default this would merge from the upstream remote tracking ref (probably `origin/master`), and if that hasn't moved since you last pulled `master` it would say "already up to date".

To fix this, escape the #, as in

```
git merge \#611
```

or

```
git merge '#611'
```

Or don't use `#` in your branch names, would also be an option.

Comment: i created a new branch with master as base, merged with \#611, and everything worked. Thanks. Also, lesson learned! not to use the issue #number as branch name!